# copying a text from one file and pasting into other using shell script

Tags: shell-script

I want to copy the number in a particular line from one text file and paste that number to other text file, how to do this using shell scripting.
For example in file1 I have a line

Total Time: 2.3456.

I want to copy 2.3456 and paste into another file. The line number for this line is not always the same.

Comment: How will you choice the line in which you want to paste a number?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 awk '/Total Time/ {print $3} ' source_file > dest_file
```

- you can use `>>` to append

if there are many line with Total Time, you can narrow using

```
awk '$1 == "Total" && $2 == "Time:"  {print $3}  ' source_file > dest_file
```

Comment: `$1$2 == "TotalTime:"` seems shorter

Comment: unless there is a line like `"T otaltime:"` ...

Comment: Are you serious? Do you beleve in it?